# Stopping .bashrc without exiting shell

Tags: bash, error-handling

My .bashrc file is modularized and I've got some error checking in it. In bash scripts, I typically have a function _errexit (or something similar) that I call when I detect an error and want to exit.

In the case of my bashrc file(s), I don't want to exit (it would close the shell) - but I do want to display an error message and stop processing immediately.

Any ideas how this might be possible?

Answer (score 5):

In BASH you can use the `return` built-in:

> **return [n]**
>
> Causes a function to exit with the return value specified by n.  If n
>   is omitted, the  return status is that of the last command executed in
>   the function body.  **If used outside a function, but during execution of
>   a script by the .  (source) command,  it  causes  the shell to stop
>   executing that script and return either n or the exit status of the last
>   command executed within the script as the exit status of  the  script.**
>   If used outside a function and not during execution of a script by .,
>   the return status is false.  Any command associated with the RETURN trap
>   is executed before execution resumes after the function or script.

For other shells it might work differently of course.

If you can possibly rewrite the main script as a loop, you could use the `break` statement based on the outcome of the loop command.

Answer (score 1):

Check the result of your processing and continue only when nothing has failed.

```
module_1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   display_error_function
else
   module_2
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      display_error_function
   else
      echo OK
   fi
fi
```

When you have a lot of modules, consider an extra shell variable.
EDIT: With the extra variable you can prevent deep-nesting (just repeat the if-block).

```
ERRORSFOUND=0
...
if [[ ${ERRORSFOUND} -eq 0 ]]; then
   module_x
   if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
      ERRORSFOUND=1
   fi
fi
```

Comment: OP is asking exactly about how not to continue - i.e. what exactly should `display_error_function` (in your parlance) look like as not to exit the shell completely. I take it he already has something along these lines in his script.

Comment: @peterph: That "not to continue" part is handled in Walter A's answer by putting all the rest of the script in the `else` part. However if there are many modules, this might give an undesirably deep nesting.

Comment: @celtschk: The second code fragment (with an extra shell variable) was introduced to prevent deep nesting. You can repeat the if-test for a lot of module_x calls. When 1 call fails, you fall, all subsequent tests on ERRORSFOUND will fail.

Comment: @celtschk my point is, that it doesn't really stop processing the script, unless you do the nesting. And that will make the script cluttered. Unless you put it into a loop in which case one could use the `break` statement. However, a loop is not always the best form of putting such a script together.